# Windows 11 networking issues

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-11

I have this strange issue with my Widnows 11 laptop, where the wifi connection is very unstable.
It is very random and sometimes it gets better after a while.
Here is an example of `ping www.google.com` over a long time:

```
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=55ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=17ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=17ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=22ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=68ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=24ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=17ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=23ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=559ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=21ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=22ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=25ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=22ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=18ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=17ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=21ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=202ms
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=23ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=22ms
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=62ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=20ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=31ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms
Request timed out.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=200ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=25ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=17ms
Request timed out.
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=132ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004: time=19ms

Ping statistics for 2a00:1450:4009:823::2004:
    Packets: Sent = 167, Received = 99, Lost = 68 (40% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 17ms, Maximum = 559ms, Average = 39ms
```

Because of that playing any online games is borderline impossible.
My MAC sitting right next to the Win11 laptop does not have this issues, ever. So I am assuming it is not a router.
Unsure what I should check/investigate - could any1 advise?
I am using a WIFI dongle, a good one - [ASUS usb-ac68](https://www.asus.com/uk/networking-iot-servers/adapters/all-series/usb-ac68/).

---

EDIT

I have tested the connection with another WiFi dongle - the same issue. No other devices connected to my network are experiencing it and so I am pretty sure it is something to do with the OS. Unsure where to take it from here tho.

---

EDIT 2

Just tried connecting the laptop to the router via ethernet cable and that works just fine.

Comment: Try a different USB Wireless Adapater - That is what I would do.

Comment: Start by pinging your local router. If you have the possibility, also test with IPv4. If the drops don't happen pinging the local router, the problem's on the internet connection. If they do, a possible reason is interference - moving the router to a different location, preferably on top of a wardrobe or something so it's high up might resolve the problem.

Comment: What have you done so far to test the issue (except using a different device)? Does it change when you disconnect all other WLAN devices and stay with the laptop in close proximity to the WLAN router? What happens when you connect to a different WLAN? e.g. via Hotspot on your mobile?

Comment: Is it a problem with the hardware? You could try booting up a different operating system. Windows 11 is very buggy, but I would be surprised if such a big issue was still around. An easier solution would be to test Ethernet, you can get wireless Ethernet ports, which connect to Wi-Fi and then output Ethernet, to make sure that it isn’t a problem with your computer’s wireless.

Comment: Tested with another dongle - same issue. Unfortunately I do not have access to wireless ethernet ports

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk what about the other tests I suggested?